# SwiftUI view management for CoreData one to many relationship

Tags: swiftui

My data model has several projects, each project has zero or more hazards.
A hazard belongs to only one project. This is setup as relationships in model. Simplifies as below..

PROJECT
entities:
pName
relationships:
hazards

HAZARD
entities:
hName
relationships:
project

In my EditProject view there's the following code to make the link

```
      NavigationLink(destination: ListHazards (selected: self.project),
                     label: {Text("Associated Hazards")})
```

and in ListHazards view

`@Binding var selected: Projects`

as I want then to display the hazards view as

```
  init(project: Projects) {
  self.project = project
```

```
  var body: some View {
      List {
         ForEach(listOfHazards, id: \.self) { hazard in
```

But I cant seem to be able to pass Project to listform, let alone list...
I get error

*Cannot convert value of type 'Projects' to expected argument type 'Binding'*

What am I doing wrong?